# How to capture pattern mtach line and next n line in postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

```
select regexp_replace(
E'In most cases regexp_matches() should be used with the g flag,' ||
E'since if you only want\n the first match, it''s easier and more efficient'||
E'to use regexp_match(). \nHowever, regexp_match() only exists in '||
E'PostgreSQL version 10 and up. When working in older\n versions,' ||
E'a common trick is to place a regexp_matches() call in a sub-select,'||
E'for\n example:', E'(.|\n)*?(PostgreSQL version 10)', E'\n');
```

Return

```
                                  regexp_replace                                  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                 +
  and up. When working in older                                                  +
  versions,a common trick is to place a regexp_matches() call in a sub-select,for+
  example:
(1 row)
```

But I'm looking for a generic regex pattern that will capture pattern line (whole line) and following n line.(n as a integer, can be 1 or 2 or 3).

I even tried:

```
select regexp_replace(
E'In most cases regexp_matches() should be used with the g flag,' ||
E'since if you only want\n the first match, it''s easier and more efficient'||
E'to use regexp_match(). \nHowever, regexp_match() only exists in '||
E'PostgreSQL version 10 and up. When working in older\n versions,' ||
E'a common trick is to place a regexp_matches() call in a sub-select,'||
E'for\n example:', E'.*?(PostgreSQL version 10).*?\n', E'\n');
```

expected result:
**Match one line**: The whole line contain string "PostgreSQL version 10" will become newline, others remain the same.

**Match two line**: The whole line contain string "PostgreSQL version 10" will become newline, the following line will also become new line, others remain the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this regex should work:

```
(\s\\n).*(PostgreSQL version 10)(.*?(\\n\s)){T}
```

where `T` is the number of line you would like replaced with `\n`. [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/OZWMKT/1).

**Explanation:**

- `(\s\\n)` - matches the string starting with a space, `\` and `n`.
- `.*` - match anything between
- `(PostgreSQL version 10)` - match the words *PostgreSQL version 10*
- `(.*?(\\n\s))` - `.*?` matches any character except line terminator between 0 and unlimited times. `\\` matches for `\` while `n` does the same for char `n`. `\s` matches whitespace char.
- `{T}` - matches the last group i.e. `(.*?(\\n\s))` `T` times.

**Edit:**

As highlighted by OP, above regex doesn't work in Postgres 14 and 15, updated and tested regex that works in Postgres is: `(\s\n).*?(PostgreSQL version 10)(.*?(\n\s)){T}`. [DB Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=ff5ff5c4b4655dfb6bc977b15a12fc99)

Comment: Hey. Seems it does not work as intended in pg15 and pg14. see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=c0ccefd4454fd11904ef4963aec08849)

Comment: Hey, I've added an updated regex which works along with db-fiddle demo.

Comment: Hey there. It seems not working as intended still. see[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=f7dae44b07135e956f2f79f909bfee95)

Comment: It's working indeed. According to your expected input and output, it seems you're doing the replace wrong. Replace the matched pattern with `E'\n\n'` and you would get the expected output. DB-Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=4cd77649574177f1ffab227dfc11543b